# Is there a way to store WriteLine into a string variable?

Tags: c#

In using methods, I need to return a string from a method into the main.
The string needs to contain the output of the program. The main needs to be the one that displays the string.

```
public static string GetFlightInfo(int flight, int[] flightNumbers, string[] codes, string[] names, string[] times)
{
    int y = 0;
    string random = "";
    for (int x =0; x<flightNumbers.Length; ++x)
    {
        if (flight == flightNumbers[x])
        {
            Write("Flight #{0} {1} {2} Scheduled at: {3}", flight, codes[x], names[x], times[x]);
            y++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (y == 0)
    {
        WriteLine("Flight #{0} was not found", flight);
    }
    return random;
}
```

I want to store the WriteLine into the string random. And make the Main function display the output.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` simply follows the pattern originating from [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8), so use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
public static string GetFlightInfo(int flight, int[] flightNumbers, string[] codes, string[] names, string[] times)
{
    int y = 0;
    string random = "";
    for (int x =0; x<flightNumbers.Length; ++x)
    {
        if (flight == flightNumbers[x])
        {
            random += $"Flight #{flight} {codes[x]} {2} Scheduled at: {times[x]}\n";
            y++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (y == 0)
    {
        random += $"Flight #{flight} was not found";
    }
    return random;
}

main() {
 Console.WriteLine(GetFlightInfo(flight, flightNumbers, codes, names, times));
}
```

[$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Didn't know how to do this:
random += $"Flight #{flight} {codes[x]} {2} Scheduled at: {times[x]}\n";

Now I know. Thanks again!

Comment: @EarlPaquibol upvode and mark as answer if it helped you find the solution. that's how "thank you" is showed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a way.

```
var previous = Console.Out; // backup current state
var writer = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(writer);

GetFlightInfo(...);

Console.SetOut(previous); // restore the original state
string result = writer.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Using this way, the `WriteLine` method will write to `StreamWriter` instead of the console. You can then get the value from this `StreamWriter`.

However, it would be more correct to rewrite the method as suggested in another answer.